# Why am I losing information when I don't use generic in typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I have some questions about `TypeScript's Generics`.

- How does generics works in TypeScript?
- The documentation says that we actually are losing the information about what that type was when the function returns, but how so? It uses this code below:

  ```
  function identity(arg: any): any {
      return arg; 
  }
  ```
- What can I do with `generic` can I still with `any`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The documentation says that we actually are losing the information about what that type was when the function returns, but how so?

This function loses information about the argument:

```
function identity(arg: any): any {
    return arg; 
}

const foo = identity(123); // typeof foo == `any`
```

The following function (using a generic) [*constrains*](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/generics.html) the return type of the function to *match* the input type. This perserves (and flows) the type of the argument to the return type:

```
function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg; 
}

const foo = identity(123); // typeof foo == `number`
```

Comment: When I do this: console.log(typeof foo); it returns for me, number.
1. tsc example_generic.ts
2. node example_generic.js